# How to enable screen rotation programatically in android?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-orientation, screen-rotation

I need to enable this function for an activity of mine:

I want it to be like this:
[image: enabled]

when it's like this:

[image: disabled]

please note that I DON'T want to set it fixed as PORTRAIT, LANDSCAPE or any other orientation, I really want the user to rotate the device freely.

Do I need to request any permission on manifest? Is it even posible to do that? I couldn't find anything that actually work, for example:

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

just does not work at all.

Comment: The option you are pointing to is a system wide option which you cannot change, I do not even believe this is something you can control only in your app either

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to change the device settings or just for your app?

If you want to change it for your app:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);
    setContentView(view);
}
```